# Can we give constant as key name in intent?

Tags: android-intent

I want to display the data in the next activity ,The data is the content in the listview on which item the user is clicked ,Now i am trying to send this data through intent,i want to give the key name with some string constant .Is it correct way?or it shouldnt done ..
Actually i tried but i am getting errors on retriving StringExtras.Please help in this
Thanks in regards

Comment: Post your code and the logcat or compiler errors

Answer (score 0):

yes this is the way to send data between activities
in firstActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(i);
```

and  then in secondActivity

```
Bundle extras = getString().getExtras();
String a= extras.getString("data");
```

if you got some errors please check if you are passing an int and trying to get an string o something like that. and send us the error console

Comment: Thanks Xenione I know this procedure ..my bad i didn't explain well what i need in the question.In my first activity I want to pass some string to another activity i want to give  String constant as a key..How to retrieve this in the next activity.??

Comment: do you mean String constant as a Value?, the key is always a String constant is just a reference name.